# GA4 Analytics track click event and check if working

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I have my tracking code here already in the site:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X');
</script>
```

I am using these event `ga('send', 'event', 'Link', 'Click', 'Purchase Details');` but every time I clicked on the link, it does not capture anything. Am I doing this wrong or are the event tags needed to be setup first in GA?

this is my onclick code:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Link', 'Click', 'LinkedIn Redirect');"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-lg"></i></a></li>
```

Comment: how do you check if it captures anything?

Comment: I go to Google analytics page then check if events under behavior captures with the associated label. am I doing this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're debugging it incorrectly. It takes up to two days for GA to populate the events.

Either use Real time data in GA, or even closer to the click - use the Network tab in your dev tools.

Comment: ohhh, so when I add the GA Events on the links, I have to wait 2 days for it? I don't have to set them up on analytics? sorry, kina new to this one.

Comment: any GA hits take up to two days to appear. They may appear in a few minutes, but it depends and GA claims that it can take up to two days. Usually vast majority of events are there next day. But you still can debug it real time as I indicated above.

Comment: Thanks for this information! but about the events, do I have to set them up somewhere? or I can justt add them on onclick element like I did here:
I've read some articles creating them in google tag manager.

<li><a href="#" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Link', 'Click', 'LinkedIn Redirect');"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-lg"></i></a></li>

btw I'm using GA4

Comment: you don't need to set up events. once you send them, they're there. Make sure your property ID in the code is the same that you're looking at in web.